# Salvaged transformer creating a short when connected to 230v in EU

Tags: transformer, short-circuit

Probably this is a noob question but i can't find an answer on the web.

I salvaged a transformer from an old radio. I wanted to test it, so i began to wire live to the primary coil and neutral to the other end of the primary. I didn't do anything with the ground wire, should i? I connected my voltmeter to the secondary coil. I plugged it in and... the fuse switched off. The fuse in the meter cupboard, i didn't have any connected to my transformer.

Thanks,

Comment: several things to check here: a) what is 'the other end of the primary'? b) are you sure it is a mains transformer and not something like a speaker LF transformer (SMT)? c) what do you get when you measure the resistance of the primary winding?

Comment: A) The primary coil has 2 wires, i meant the other wire of the primary coil (Sorry, english isn't my first language)

Comment: B) i'm quite sure    C)maybe i messed up with the primary and secondary. As i have wired it as i explained in the question, the primary has 1 ohm and the secondary 133 ohm.

Comment: Yes. the primary winding's DC resistance in a mains transformer would be higher than that of the secondary.
As for the ground wire, it should be, well, grounded :-) so your circuit breaker would save your life in case it is shorted to its core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the primary has 1 ohm and the secondary 133 ohm

Sounds like you got primary and secondary the wrong way round - always, for an AC step-down transformer the primary DC resistance will be significantly greater than the secondary DC resistance.

However, without a picture there's no guarantee that the primary is suitable for AC mains voltages.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help! I knew it was a noob question :)

Comment: It's got to be worth posting a picture for safety reasons. Electrocution hurts!

Comment: Well, i don't have it wired up at the moment. But how should i ground it properly?

Comment: Posting a picture is the best way to get decent answers.

Comment: if it is meant to be grounded (as you said), then usually you would place it in a case and attach a triple-pole mains cable, properly strain-relieved with the ground wire longest so that it will detach last. and use a standard mains plug (in EU: "Schuko")

Comment: Got to finish what i'm doing at the moment. I'll send a picture in around 20 minutes

Comment: How do i add a picture from mobile?

Comment: @joel I've never added one from a phone before but no problem, wait until you get by a PC and leave me a comment.